# Is the File Transfer code correct in my PHP?

Tags: php, file, download, content-type, content-disposition

I have this [page](http://royaltyfreesoundbank.com/jgsnmuegvuzebazfoz/index.php?route=module/cart/download&order_download_id=66) that is supposed to be a download for a song. The download works in firefox for me but in chrome and safari nothing happens..here is my code

```
    public function download() {
    if (isset($this->request->get['order_download_id'])) {
        $order_download_id = $this->request->get['order_download_id'];
    } else {
        $order_download_id = 0;
    }
    $download_info = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_download od LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o ON (od.order_id = o.order_id) WHERE o.customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId(). "' AND o.order_status_id > '0' AND o.order_status_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_download_status') . "' AND od.order_download_id = '" . (int)$order_download_id . "'");

    if ($download_info->row) {
        $file = DIR_DOWNLOAD . $download_info->row['filename'];
        $mask = basename($download_info->row['mask']);
        $mime = 'application/octet-stream';
        $encoding = 'binary';

        if (!headers_sent()) {
            if (file_exists($file)) {
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: ' . $encoding);
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . ($mask ? $mask : basename($file)) . '"');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
                $file = readfile($file, 'rb');
                print($file);
            } else {
                exit('Error: Could not find file ' . $file . '!');
            }
        } else {
            exit('Error: Headers already sent out!');
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried all kinds of different things to get this to work but nothing is happening in the two browsers...any ideas or help will be appreciated...

Comment: I don't think you want to print the return value of readfile -- you've already sent the length of the content and that would be unexpected (plus it'd break the file on the receiver's end).

Comment: Do you get a file if you remove the redirect at the bottom? I don't know enough about IE, but it may just read the header and follow the redirect stream before processing the response body.

Comment: There's is no Content-Transfer-Encoding in HTTP. Please remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readfile` returns the number of bytes sent, and needs not to be printed out. You should remove the line `print($file);`. Otherwise, you'll send more bytes than the `Content-Length` header specifies, and that will lead some HTTP clients to discard your answer.

Also, consider strange file names such as

```
"\r\nLocation: http://evil.com\r\n\r\n<script>alert('XSS');</script>
```

Are you handling that correctly?

Comment: I removed the line and still no go...any other ideas

Comment: @Tamer Can you give us a specific download URL? I can't find a download link on the page you posted.

Comment: http://royaltyfreesoundbank.com/jgsnmuegvuzebazfoz/index.php?route=module/cart/download&order_download_id=66

Comment: @Tamer When I request that URL, all I get is a redirect. Are you sure it's the correct one?

Comment: try http://royaltyfreesoundbank.com/jgsnmuegvuzebazfoz/index.php?route=module/cart/download&order_download_id=72

Comment: try in firefox...should i put an exit of some debug code or remove the redirect to make it easier to help me

Comment: @Tamer Correction: I don't get an HTML link, but a redirect to an HTML document. Header: `http://royaltyfreesoundbank.com/jgsnmuegvuzebazfoz/index.php?route=module/cart/download&order_download_id=72` (and no body)

Comment: @Tamer That is using Firefox. Please remove the redirect and try it with a fresh browser profile (or after clearing your cookies).

Comment: what can i do on my end to help you help me

Comment: @Tamer As I said, remove the redirect, and before you give us the link, try it with a fresh browser profile.

Comment: i did and all i get is a white screen weird...in my question i have all my code for the function...do you see anything off

Comment: i see a partial problem...its not getting in the if block if ($download_info->row)

Answer (score 0):

See your syntax near

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name_with_space. '"');
```

OR it can be

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='".$file_name_with_space."'" );
```

Here the game is in Quotes only it will be treated as part of the string if it is written properly else will crash.

It works in all browser. IE, FF, Chrome, SAFARI I checked it personally so goahead.

Comment: note that this will not work with non-ASCII characters; see RFC 6266.